# Optimal placement of a pocket dimension?

Tags: magic, humans, dimensions

The main character of one of my stories just met a person specialized in magical tattoos, my character has chosen a tattoo which is linked to a pocket dimension.

But **where should the protagonist choose to place the tattoo?**

He needs somewhere where he could easily access it for drawing weapons (that will be great for surprise attack/assassination).

Also not too visible to keep it as a special/secret move (this point is less important and can be negligible if necessary)

How the tattoo works:

- It uses some kind of "magical" ink that does not wear off and is linked to the body. But it must be place on the flesh of the owner of the tattoo so under the clothes of the character, otherwise it has no effect.
- The tattoo must have a circular shape and be closed off.
- It uses the "life force" of the character to open the pocket dimension so if he is unconscious (or dies) it can no longer be opened.
- The character can simply open this pocket dimension by thought and close it too.
- Can only be closed if there is nothing currently going through (so no use in combat like closing it to cut in half something that's goes through it).
- The opening of the pocket dimension has a maximum diameter of 25 cm.

Additional information about the pocket dimension :

- It is only accessible from the owner's tattoo (doing a copy of the tattoo on another person will create a new pocket dimension).
- The pocket dimension looks like the interior of a safe with approximately  1 m³ of space.

**Edit :** The size was approximately, but I had imagined that the character will organize the dimension to have some kind of  rack/stand for his weapons in the pocket dimension, so no problem to reach a weapon when he need it.

Comment: This is a cool idea, but the choices of characters (circumstances) are off-topic.  If you think about it, the placement of the tattoo on the body has nothing to do with a rule of your world.  He could place it inside his left nostril, if he had a good enough reason.  It's too story-based.  Here's examples: his left forearm if he's right-handed, his right if he's left-handed, his outer forearm if he draws swords, his inner forearm if he draw arrows. etc.  VTC OT:TSB.

Comment: If this is a tattoo on character's body, and it is 1 m (or more) deep, how long are his hands?

Comment: @Alexander I am not sure what do you mean by "how long are his hands?" , my character is an adult male human if this help.

Comment: You know how the average video game hero pulls all those weapons out of his ass...?

Comment: What Alexander means is "if the pocket is 1m deep, how can he reach in far enough to reach the bottom?". It would mean only a limited few places are viable, like the tigh.

Comment: oh ok, hope my edit fix the problem mentioned.

Comment: I assume you'd need a bit of extra magic to help with organization. Without magic, if he ever fumbles something and it falls of the "rack", he would have a very hard time finding it again. Traditionally, [Bag of Holding](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BagOfHolding) either have some kind of "magical fetch" or an entry big enough so the owner can climb inside.

Comment: THAT's where Jack Harkness hid that holdout gun!

Comment: How can you have a spherical tattoo?

Comment: @John, i meant circular shape, my mistake, it's has been edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is going to get weird really fast so first some assumptions:

- Anything inside the pocket will not have "weight" for the wearer. So filling it full with water will not make the user heavier.
- The surface area of the tatoo will be the "top" of the pocket, even though it's likely to be Curved as no bodypart is completely flat.
- The curvature of the tatoo will not bend or destroy the objects passing through, no matter how weird it needs to bend to fit through the uneven tatoo the object will experience no real change.

I'd go for the inside of the fore-arm.

I imagine this character needing armor and such, so he could wear a vambrace or simply a swashbuckling shirt so you can just roll back the sleeves and reach in. Advantage is that you can place your fore-arm all the way up your shoulder and reach to it's depth. As long as the Vambrace isnt tied to the places where the tatoo is it can stay on even when the tatoo is open.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vambrace#/media/File%3ALeft_Arm_Defense_(Vambrace)_MET_DP-12882-028.jpg

This is ofcourse where things are going to be weird.

The average fore-arm is 24cm in circumference (https://www.hindawi.com/journals/amed/2014/592642/tab1/, mileage may vary). So you could make it circle your entire arm. Since your arm is still "there" in the tunnel formed by the hole your hand wont fall off. Assuming all parts of the surface area of the tatoo is concidered the "top" of the pocket it will depend on how much surface area is pointed to the ground if the item will fall out or not, assuming gravity from "outside" the box affects the items within. But since its unlikely you'll have it open when you have your fore-arm pointed downwards it will likely not be a problem, and even a benefit when you want to shake something out quickly.

I'm assuming the distortion when putting something in or out of this pocket will not do anything to the object or you would need a perfectly smooth object for the tattoo to push anything through in one piece. So the object may look like it would in a distorted droplet of water as you push it in the box.

Now you can use it: in battle you can open the pocket and have weapons "fall through" your arm, while in reality they will travel down and up through the pocket in a very weird way and end up on the other side, the sudden acceleration of passing through 1m of space where you'd expect a few cm of arm will be felt as a sudden higher resistance. With a Vambrace over it you could have the pocket filled with material to support the Vambrace, meaning you could have someone strike your Vambrace (or clothing) and it actually hits 1m3 of steel beneath, making them real surprised about your "invulnerable" arm and "extreme strength" as your arm doesnt even move from the blow.

Comment: Yeah your assumption are correct, i didn't think i needed to add hem, perhaps i should edit that, good  answer too, like the whole arm tattoo idea.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what kinds of weapons your character uses.

For **daggers** I could easily see tattoos on the wrists. This way he can activate them in a quick succession to maybe throw at his opponents or just perform a quick draw.

Longer weapons like **swords, bats or even lances** could come out of the palm of the hand, if they're not too wide.

For wide weapons like **bows, greatswords and guns**, the character could have a giant tatoo in his chest. It wouldn't be quick or practical during a fight, since these weapons are heavy and probably need to be taken out carefully. But with practice, if you have a few seconds, it could be done with some degree of hastiness.

---

If you need good references to characters with similar abilites check these out:

- **Ramona Flowers** from **Scott Pilgrim**: She has a bag from which she can draw a huge hammer (will look for the video to put here later);
- **Hermione Granger** from **Harry Potter**: She has a similar bag, called an "undetectable space expanding spell" or something, which acts kind of like Ramona's bag;
- **Kimimaro** from **Naruto**: This character has the ability to multiply his own bones. By doing so, he's capable of drawing bone swords from his arms and legs;
- **Ransik** from **Power Rangers - Time Force**: Like Kimimaro, this character can draw swords from his knee and from his elbow - only they're made of steel, not bone.
- **Emi Isuzu** from **Tenjou Tenge**: This character is an assassin that uses hidden blades. Her power consists of an illusory spell to hide her true form. To everyone, she looks like a very thin teenager, but she's actually incredibly fat. She hides her blades in the folds of her fat, where she can easily draw and throw them at enemies. If your character is fat enough, this could also be an option.

Answer (score 0):

> He need somewhere where he could easily access it for drawing weapons (that will be great for surprise attack/assassination).
>
> Also not to visible to keep it as a special/secret move

Do it on the prison wallet.

This has prescedents in media. A certain Marvel super hero has confessed to doing something similar in comics.

[image: If it works for Deadpool, it works for you]

Comment: Actually, no, we're not all adults here.  I haven't clicked the link for purely personal reasons, but are you sure it must be included?

Comment: @JBH I just wanted to give an example so people can probe further if they want.

Comment: Yeah... we actually do have children who use this site.  I apologize that I flagged the answer "rude or abusive."  It's rude (in the traditional sense of the word), but I'm not very repentant.  Sarcasm could have been achieved elsewise.

Comment: Please present your answer in a way that does not require viewing NSFW content.  Describing the solution in your answer would be the best way, as we also don't want link-only answers even if they're safe links.

Comment: Ok, nsfw link removed.

Answer (score 0):

### Stomach

- It's easily accessible by either hand.
- It allows for the largest possible opening size.
- Can be hidden without arousing suspicion. It's normal to wear a shirt all the time.
- Allows for quick access. Just pull the shirt up and it's right there. Wear the shirt un-tucked if worried about very quick access.

Comment: *"It allows for the largest possible opening size."*. Nope. You've probably never seen the goatse meme.

Comment: @Renan!  People were starting to forget!  I was, anyway.  But not now.